# Ruby comparison with an OR operator - strange behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Below code should be a good example of strange Ruby behaviour when it comes to the OR operator:

```
  def search_by_name_active
    if request.path == (name_search_registrants_path \
      || new_registrant_path)
      'active'
    end
  end
```

And the specs:

```
  describe "#search_by_name_active" do
    it "should return active if current page is new_registrant" do
      allow(helper.request).to receive(:path).and_return(new_registrant_path)
      expect(helper.search_by_name_active).to eq('active')
    end
  end
```

Which gives me an error:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(helper.search_by_name_active).to eq('active')

   expected: "active"
        got: nil
```

If I remove the brackets:

```
  def search_by_name_active
    if request.path == name_search_registrants_path \
      || new_registrant_path
      'active'
    end
  end
```

The first spec will passed but not the below one:

```
it "should return nil if current page is not search_by_name" do
  allow(helper.request).to receive(:path).and_return(id_search_registrants_path)
  expect(helper.search_by_name_active).to be_nil
end

 Failure/Error: expect(helper.search_by_name_active).to be_nil

   expected: nil
        got: "active"
```

WTF?! Is there any other way to write this logical equation besides an additional if like below?

```
  def search_by_name_active
    if request.path == name_search_registrants_path
      'active'
    elsif request.path == new_registrant_path
      'active'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Don't use it in the first place? `[name_search_registrants_path, new_registrant_path].include?(request.path)`. That makes it easier to use a local variable so you don't have to use the line continuation operator.

Comment: Or the reverse `request.path.in? [name_search_registrants_path, new_registrant_path]`.

Comment: You want `request.path == name_search_registrants_path || request.path == new_registrant_path`, i.e. you combine whole comparisons via `||`, not just the right-hand values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is expected in all programming languages, not just ruby. To simplify your example a little:

```
x == (a || b)
```

...is **not** equivalent to:

```
(x == a) || (x == b)
```

The first expression is evaluating `(a || b)` *before* comparing it to `x`. So you're only comparing `x` to *one* of the values, not *both* of them.

The generic way to write this in all programming languages would to instead use the second code sample above. Or in other words, using your specific example:

```
if request.path == name_search_registrants_path \
  || request.path == new_registrant_path
```

Or, there are a couple of ruby-specific ways we can shorten this code:

```
# Works in any ruby code
if [name_search_registrants_path, new_registrant_path].include?(request.path)

# Works in any rails code
if request.path.in? [name_search_registrants_path, new_registrant_path]
```

The second example is rails-specific, because it's using [this extension to the core ruby language](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-in-3F).